# Warning de Nodejs Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Me sale en la consola este warning:

> (node:5627) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Intenté de todo para que no me aparezca más. Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var assert = require('assert');
var User = require("./models/user").User;
var app = express();

app.use("/estatico", express.static('public'));

app.use(bodyParser.json()); //para peticiones application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.render("index");
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    User.find(function(err,doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        res.render("login");
    })

});

app.post('/users', function(req, res){
var user_login = new User({email: req.body.email, 
                           password: req.body.password,
                           password_confirmation: req.body.password_confirmation,
                           username: req.body.username
                          });

promise = user_login.save();

console.log(assert.ok(promise instanceof require('mpromise')));

return promise.then(function(us) {
    res.send("Datos guardados")
},function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(String(err));
        res.send("Los datos no han sido guardados")
    };
})

});

app.listen(8080);
```

El código funciona, guarda los datos en caso de que el formulario sea completado correctamente y lanza los errores en caso de que el formulario no sea completado correctamente, pero ¿porque el warning?

Answer (score 2):

Viendo la documentación de
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
Me ha ayudado en algo

En el ejemplo de la documentación esta usando la librería de promesas bluebird, pero yo prefiero usar las promesas nativas de ES6.

En el archivo donde tu estés llamando a mongoose.connect debes colocar lo siguiente:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/baseDatos');
```

Answer (score 1):

Funciona correctamente porque no es un error, si no una advertencia de que una de las dependencias de Mongoose, en este caso, su propia especificación de `Promises` está en desuso y recomienda usar otra librería de `Promises`.

[**Documentación**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#plugging-in-your-own-promises-library) :

> Mientras que mpromise es suficiente para casos básicos,usuarios
>   avanzados puede que quieran usar su librería de Promises favorita como
>   bluebird o simplemente usar la librería de Promises nativa en ES6.
>   Solo debes actalizar el valor de la  variable mongoose.Promise para qe
>   apunte al constructor del Objeto Promise y moongoose lo usará.

```
var query = Band.findOne({name: "Guns N' Roses"});

// Uso de Promises nativo
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
assert.equal(query.exec().constructor, global.Promise);

// Uso de bluebird
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
assert.equal(query.exec().constructor, require('bluebird'));

// Uso de Q.
mongoose.Promise = require('q').Promise;
assert.ok(query.exec() instanceof require('q').makePromise);
```